# How to use only 1 grid layout for both header and detail with itemscontrol?

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, grid, itemscontrol

Now, when i want to create a table with a header and detail i have to define a columns 2 times for each row. the first row is header and the second row i used itemscontrol to binding data.

below is my sample code.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource WidthColumn}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ListTitle}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ListDetailTitle}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ListValueTitle}" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource ="{Binding Samples}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type parameters:SampleParameters}">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource WidthColumn}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Position}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding Name}" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Name="Button"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Can it use only 1 time grid layout? or there is another solution to do with?

Comment: Maybe you're looking more towards a `DataGrid`?

Comment: For my screen, sometimes there are more than 1 header row. It depend on the data. but it still need the same columndefinitions (column count and width).